# Rest template keeps getting HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, resttemplate

I keep getting HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 null when doing a rest call via rest template.

```
 private HttpHeaders getAuthHeaderWithToken() {
ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/user", HttpMethod
        .OPTIONS, new HttpEntity<>(getAuthHeader()), String.class);

    String token = response.getHeaders().getFirst("Set-Cookie").split("=")
        [1].split(";")[0];
    String sessionId = response.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie").get(1).split("=")
        [1].split(",")[0];

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    httpHeaders.add("Authorization", authHeader);
    httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpHeaders.add("Accept", "*/*");
    httpHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionId);
    httpHeaders.add("X-XSRF-TOKEN", token);
return httpHeaders;
}

public void update () {
HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(createPutRequestObject(ticketNo,
          status, resourceName), getAuthHeaderWithToken());

ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.exchange(URL + "/"
          + id, HttpMethod.PUT, httpEntity, String.class);
}
```

LOGS

```
 headers     ---- getAuthHeader  -- [Accept:"application/json", Authorization:"Basic cnVwOjJLOHlzSWtyUUo=", Content-Type:"application/json"]
 ---------------- 
 ---------------- 
response -- [Set-Cookie:"XSRF-TOKEN=2ea53952-1846-41ba-b82a-99b991a3047c;path=/", "JSESSIONID=54F4C9452821DEBA795E9E7B10A2565A;path=/;HttpOnly", X-Application-Context:"application:8080", Allow:"GET,HEAD", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY", Content-Length:"0", Date:"Mon, 17 Jun 2019 12:50:24 GMT"]
 ---------------- 
 ---------------- 
httpHeaders -- [Accept:"application/json", "*/*", Authorization:"Basic cnVwOjJLOHlzSWtyUUo=", Content-Type:"application/json", Cookie:"JSESSIONID=54F4C9452821DEBA795E9E7B10A2565A", X-XSRF-TOKEN:"2ea53952-1846-41ba-b82a-99b991a3047c"]
 ----------------
```

And ERROR

```
 Failed to update user
response received : org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 null
```

And on other end where request is being made

```
2019-06-17 13:55:09.531 DEBUG 17719 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [{timestamp=Mon Jun 17 13:55:09 BST 2019, status=403, error=Forbidden, message=Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@72b3da85]
2019-06-17 13:55:09.532 DEBUG 17719 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2019-06-17 13:55:09.532 DEBUG 17719 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

I have debugged at Csrf filter level and found that token passed in header in null I don't understand why other spring boot app is failling to detect it.

It Works fine from web app with the same header on users API. It's just the when using rest template to call users API it's given me the error.

And my CORS config is that

```
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
```

Comment: Please print the response.getHeaders().getFirst("Set-Cookie")

Comment: Hi @Tianxin response.getHeaders() XSRF-TOKEN=2ea53952-1846-41ba-b82a-99b991a3047c;path=/